# How to detect focus of any text fields in any applications?

Tags: gnome

I need to detect the focus of a text field on the screen programmatically. Like a virtual keyboard would. I've tried to look a little on the side of Gnome, without success. Also, if the solution could be usable in Rust, that would be great.
I imagine it depends a lot on the OS and the DE but if you have any leads, I'll take them. Thanks